# Audi A3 starter turns on during drive

Tags: audi, starter, a3

I have an Audi A3 Ambition car and have bought it in August, 2017. The seller mentioned he built in a start button, so the car needs contact using the key first, then the motor starts by pressing a button (similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPvp39jmhiM)).

But after a while, issues with starting the motor began. At first the car  didn't start *sometimes* in the first attempt. Another attempt of starting the motor was successful. Until the day, the car could not be turned on anymore. I brought the car to the service for repairment. They changed the starter which was obviously wrong. But there was a suspicion, that the real cause was custom electronics / electronics modification. The starter turned on again, after two weeks, on a trip to vacation. The suspicion is the electronics as the mechanic said.

The question is: what can cause an random activation of starter during drive so is getting destroyed?

Comment: This is probably not answerable without knowing exactly what equipment the previous owner installed, and what changes were made to the car's wiring. If this were my car, I'd start by removing the things that were added, and returning the car's electrical system to its stock configuration.

Comment: I don't think I could agree more with @David - This is spot on advice. I really don't think this question is answerable, either.

Answer (score 2):

if i was a betting man i would bet the previous owner did a less than stellar job of wiring it and now 2 frayed wires are shorting against each other activating the starter. Pull back the dash and fix their mistake